# Sum of Coefficients in a Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the sum of the coefficients of the terms in the expansion of $(2x+3y-3z)^7$.

I know how to do this for binomials, but I was not able to apply the same logic to a trinomial.

I believe my other method is faulty, but here it is: $2+3-3 = 2$, and $2^7 = 128$, which is the sum of the coefficients.

Please tell me if there is a basic method that can be used to solve this problem in a general case and if my method is correct/faulty.

Comment: What precisely is your method, and why do you believe it doesn't extend to trinomials?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set $$x = y = z = 1$$ With these values the expansion is the sum of the coefficient.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the OP did in his third paragraph? You get some credit for clarifying what he did, but you would get more if you explain that you *are* referring to what he did, state what he did is not faulty, and explain why.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I didn't read what the OP wrote in the third paragraph, I simply wrote an answer

Comment: In that case, you deserve more credit than I thought. Good work! +1 You still may want to clarify.

Comment: I did not know what I was doing when I did that problem, but I still got it right somehow using that method. WLOG clarifies why it works.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> Find the sum of the coefficients of the terms in the expansion of
>   $\ds{\pars{2x + 3y - 3z}^{7}:\ {\large ?}}$

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
{7! \over a!\, b!\, c!}2^{a}3^{b}\pars{-3}^{c}\delta_{a + b + c,7}}
\\[5mm]&=7!\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
{2^{a} \over a!}\,{3^{b} \over b!}\,{\pars{-3}^{c} \over c!}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z^{-a - b - c + 8}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=7!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z^{8}}\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2z}^{a} \over a!}
\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{3z}^{b} \over b!}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-3z}^{c} \over c!}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=7!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z^{8}}\,\expo{2z}\expo{3z}\expo{-3z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=7!\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\expo{2z} \over z^{8}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=7!\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{2^{n} \over n!}\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{8 - n}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\dsc{\delta_{n,7}}}
\\[5mm]&=7!\,{2^{7} \over 7!}=2^{7}=\color{#66f}{\Large 128}
\end{align}

Comment: you made a mistake evaluating the contour integral of $z^{n-8}$ in your last step; it actually sifts out the $n=7$ term rather than $n=8$; correcting this yields the answer $2^7=128$.

Comment: @oldrinb Thanks. In a long calculation 'something is always lost'. I was aware that the OP already gave he answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding (pun not intended) on WLOG's answer:

The expression $(2x+3y-3z)^7$ expands to
$$(2x+3y-3z)^7 = \sum_{\substack{0 \le i,j,k\\i+j+k=7}} (2x)^i(3y)^j(-3z)^k = \sum_{\substack{0\le i,j,k\\i+j+k=7}}2^i3^j(-3)^kx^iy^jz^k \tag{1}$$

(The notation indicates that we are summing over all combinations of nonnegative integers $i,j,k$ which sum to $7$).  Setting $x=y=z=1$ gives us
$$\sum_{\substack{0\le i,j,k\\i+j+k=7}}2^i3^j(-3)^k$$
which is exactly the sum of the coefficients.  But, on the other hand, by (1),
$$\sum_{\substack{0\le i,j,k\\i+j+k=7}}2^i3^j(-3)^k = (2+3-3)^7 = 128$$
as you observed.  Thus, the sum of the coefficients of the expansion is $128$.  Notice that this method could be extended to an arbitrary number of variables and choice of coefficients:
$$(a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_nx_n)^k = (a_1 + \cdots + a_n)^k$$